# Is this a correct implementation of the backbone.js MVC pattern?

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js

I'm refactoring an old app with **backbone.js**.

When throught the TodoList tuto, but i'm still unsure how everything should fit together.

*For now, i have :*

- A `GlobalController` that is initialized, it handles global-app-wide routing & other objects initialization.
- This `GlobalController` initialize a `GlobalAppView` (global-app-wide action, like how to handle ajax clicks) & after that, all the other controllers in my app.
- Thoses controllers, like a `TagController`, initialize its own collections, (a `BlueTagList` & a `RedTagList` that extend an `App.TagList` collection), stored in the `window` namespace (should it be in the controller namespace?).
- Then, the controller is called somewhere in my views, `TagsController->render('BlueTagListView', {el: '#container', collection : BlueTagList, data : ...});`

Is there any flows in this scheme ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think things would be clearer if Backbone.js renamed things a little.

```
Models      ->  Models
DOM subtrees->  Views ( view.el in the backbone case )
Views       ->  Controllers
Controllers ->  HashchangeController ( A specialized type of controller )
```

Backbone.js is an MVC framework but it's just the naming convention that is a bit weird. It sort of suggests that you must use the Backbone.Controller or you would just be doing a Model/View. But don't feel pressured to do so.

It is perfectly ok to build an application without a Backbone.Controller unless you
really need bookmarkable links. If you do then cool, but it is not absolutely required.
The URL bar is just another widget on the page you can write a controller to respond to.

Perhaps thinking about your components as above will make it easier for you.

Comment: Strangely enough there was a new release of Backbone.js yesterday and the owner made a breaking change by renaming Controller to Router. Obviously other people have made the same observation as myself.